# QGIS plugin, display image responses with known bounding box

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I am building a QGIS plugin. The users will fill some parameters from UI and the response image will be displayed on QGIS map.

There is a back-end service that serves images (PNG, WebP, JPEG) of given geographical bounding box (EPSG:4326, EPSG:3857).

How can I display a picture on map canvas with bounding box using Python?

Comment: One question per Question, please, as detailed in the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [`gdal:translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) :

```
# variables to modify
picture_path ="/path/to/your/picture.png" 
extent = QgsRectangle(2.05287815000000018, 44.10549260999999888, 7.19556459999999998, 46.81428704999999724)
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326)

# add picture to QGIS
picture =QgsRasterLayer(picture_path, 'picture')
# give picture the right coordinate reference system
picture.setCrs(QgsProject.instance().crs())
# use param algorithm with your extent to translate the picture
translate_param = {'INPUT': picture, 'TARGET_CRS': QgsProject.instance().crs(), 'NODATA': None,
                   'COPY_SUBDATASETS': False, 'OPTIONS': '',
                   'EXTRA': '-a_ullr '+str(extent.xMinimum())+' '+str(extent.yMaximum())+' '+str(extent.xMaximum())+' '+str(extent.yMinimum()),
                   'DATA_TYPE': 0, 'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
translate = processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:translate",  translate_param)
```